# How do I pass the name of the radio button to the Javascript for the onclick event?

Tags: php, onclick, radio-button, dom-events, alert

I have an html table having n rows. Each row has a name and 2 radio buttons. If I click a radio button, I want to show an alert that states the count of votes. How should I pass the name of the radio button to the Javascript and how should I do the counting?

Here's the PHP part:

```
list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension();
$var=0;
foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) {
    $var++;
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$k.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.( (isset($r[0])) ? $r[0] : '&nbsp;' ).'</td>';
        echo '<td><Input type = "Radio" Name ="vote'.$var.'" value= "pacada"  onclick = "AddPacada()"></td>';
        echo '<td><Input type = "Radio" Name ="vote'.$var.'" value= "toledo"  onclick = "AddToledo()"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

and here's the Javascript part:

```
function AddPacada(){
if(document.tally.pacada.checked == true){
    alert("You have clicked on Pacada.");
}
}function AddToledo(){
if(document.tally.toledo.checked == true){
    alert("You have clicked on Toledo.");
}
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `this`?

Comment: Do you mean the name or the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass it as an argument:

```
... onclick = "AddPacada(this)" ...
                         ^^^^

/* And in your function: */

function AddPacada(radio) {
    alert(radio.value);
}
```

Comment: thanks. Now I have the counts. How should I pass the counts to the php?

Comment: @PebbeBunoan: I suggest you start reading a book about the basics of javascript if you need to ask each and any of anything you can possible run over. You will progress much faster. Also there are many good introductory online resources, too, if you don't want to read a book.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onclick` in your PHP code to `onclick=tally(this)`

Then this javascript will alert the totals currently selected:

```
<script>
  var selections = new Array(); //keep track of the selections
  function tally(e) {
    val  = e.value;
    name = e.name;

    selections[name] = val;  //an associative array or "hash"

    var totals = new Array();
    for (var key in selections) {
      var selection=selections[key];
      if(totals[selection] == undefined) { //set to 1 if not already initialized
        totals[selection] = 1;
      } else {
        totals[selection] += 1;
      }
    }
    alert(val + " has been selected " + totals[val] + " times");
  }

</script>
```

Style-wise, I would try to emit the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="a" onclick="tally(this)"/>
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="b" onclick="tally(this)"/>

<input type="radio" name="var2" value="a" onclick="tally(this)"/>
<input type="radio" name="var2" value="b" onclick="tally(this)"/>
```

Note the spacing and case.